# Running c# application with C++ dll generates unable to load exception

Tags: c#, c++

I'm trying to get a simple C/C++ dll working in a .net (visual studio 2017 with framework 4.x) but all I'm getting is:

System.DllNotFoundException: 'Unable to load DLL 'OurDll.dll': The specified module could not be found. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007007E)'

I am using a sample dll from here (it includes a download to the source and full binary build):
https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/tanmayit08/unmanaged-cpp-dll-call-from-managed-c-sharp-application/

But just for ease, the dll is simply this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
extern "C"  
{
   __declspec(dllexport) int add(int a,int b) 
   {
          return a+b;
   }
   __declspec(dllexport) int subtract(int a,int b) 
   {
          return a-b;
   }
}
```

It is a 32 bit dll as shown in the project:
Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Release|Win32'">

The c# code is this:

```
    [DllImport("OurDll.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
    public static extern int subtract(int a, int b);
```

- The dll is set to export with the program, it is in the folder with the executable.
- I've explicitly made the program x86 too
- I've even used their sample bin folder and it doesn't work

So I figure between 2010 and 2018 something has changed :), for example I'm on 64 bit, but I assumed creating an x86 application or running it from their binaries would solve this...

I have also tried putting the full path in, so it is not the path that is at fault and from searching the internet it is not some other externally linked dll.

I have even used corflags to explicitly set everything as 32bit required
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: " I've explicitly made the program x86 too" which is the same as the dll?

Comment: I changed the platform in configuration manager to be x86 not 'any cpu'. 

If I download the sample from the link which includes the dll and a sample program, I get the same fault, so it's not the Vs build..

Comment: Yes - but was that for BOTH the dll or just your application?  They need to be the same.

Comment: I've updated to say I even tried their binary folder in the zip provided and get the same error. I am using the pre-made DLL from the website.

Comment: Are you sure the DLL is x86 and not x64 (64-bit)?  Are you sure the C# app's working directory is correct?  (Try running it from Windows Explorer with the DLL in the same folder)

Comment: Yes. The sample .net program they provide (with binaries) is even set as an x86 program. Like I said, they provide a full bin/obj folder for everything and that doesn't run either.

Comment: The only code in the dll is in my thread.

Comment: this is all that is in the dll project file.

<ItemDefinitionGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Debug|Win32'">

      <PreprocessorDefinitions>WIN32;_DEBUG;_WINDOWS;_USRDLL;OURDLL_EXPORTS;%(PreprocessorDefinitions)</PreprocessorDefinitions>

Comment: I've also tried using corflags to set to 32bit required for the executable.

Comment: It is a simple file-not-found error, nothing to do with bitness.  Ensure that this DLL is copied into the same directory as the C# executable.  Do note that it does not tell you anything about the "specified module", could be another DLL that this OurDll.dll depends on.  Enable loader snaps or use SysInternals' Process Monitor.

Comment: No, it is there. As I said, I've explicitly tried the full path in the program, and I've also ran the program from the command line with the dll in the same folder as the .net executable.

Comment: I've downloaded another sample DLL and get the same result. All files are in the folder. I've tried using sample functions in user32 and they run just fine.

Answer (score 1):

Solved the problem. The C++ was compiled with /MD with Visual Studio 2015. I only had the runtimes for all versions except 2015. Compiling statically with /MT fixed it.

So the general gist is you need the c++ runtime library installed, or compile your code with the runtime statically to get it to work.

thanks for all your help. Hopefully this may help somebody.